# Fn::Sub with Bash parameter substitution

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have the following aws cloudformation template where i need to perform string manipulation inside the EC2 launch template section (where in URL is a cfn template parameter)-

```
        UserData:
          Fn::Base64: !Join
            - ''
            - - !Sub |
                #!/bin/bash
                set -o xtrace
                .
                .
                git clone ${URL}
              - |
                   CFNREPO=${URL/aws.*/aws-cfn.git}
                   git clone ${CFNREPO}
              - !Sub |
                GITHUBURL: ${githubURL}
                .
                .
```

Expected Output:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -o xtrace
.
.
git clone https://www.example.com/aws-s3.git
CFNREPO=https://www.example.com/aws-cfn.git
git clone https://www.example.com/aws-cfn.git
GITHUBURL: https://github.com/other-repo-url
.
.
```

Actual Output:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -o xtrace
.
.
git clone https://www.example.com/aws-s3.git
CFNREPO=${URL/aws.*/aws-cfn.git}
git clone ${CFNREPO}
GITHUBURL: https://github.com/other-repo-url
.
.
```

Referred - [link](https://alukach.com/posts/cloudformation-sub-ref/) , but the solution is not working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct, at least from yaml perspective. This part:

```
                   CFNREPO=${URL/aws.*/aws-cfn.git}
                   git clone ${CFNREPO}
```

will be resolved when you run your code on an instance. This is not something that YAML or CloudFormation can do for you.

Comment: Ok, so this cloudformation creates a launch template which has the above mentioned lines. Now when i check the launch template , all other variables are replaced with their values but not these two lines. Variable assignment is just not working

Comment: What `${URL/aws.*/aws-cfn.git}` is supposed to be?  a bash command?

Comment: Its a url where aws.xx is to be replaced by aws-cfn.git. For example, URL = https://www.google.com/aws-s3.git . & CFNREPO(supposed to be)=https://www.google.com/aws-cfn.git

Comment: @BPoorva Sorry, its not clear what you wan to do. So `URL` is some CloudFormation parameter? Maybe update your question with more details and examples.

Comment: updated it, also you can go through the link - https://alukach.com/posts/cloudformation-sub-ref/  to understand it better.